# MYSQL: Inserting multiple results from SELECT results into a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I insert the results of multiple rows of results into MYSQL?

My SQL results are :

```
user_id |   Name   | Age
--------+----------+-----
      1 | Rob      | 23
      2 | Jenny    | 35
      3 | Brock    | 18
      4 | Samantha | 46
```

How do I insert all the results into another SQL table? I'm guessing there is a "foreach row as ...." php function. I am using Zend Framework.

Comment: There is no "s" in the end of Zend Framework name ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (user_id, name, age)
     SELECT user_id,
            name,
            age
       FROM tbl2
      WHERE ...
```

Comment: I feel embarrassed, I was doing INSERT INTO tbl VALUE (SELECT ...). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without involving PHP much. Most databases can handle that themselves:

```
INSERT INTO second_table (user_id, Name, Age)
   SELECT user_id, Name, Age
   FROM first_table
```

Here's the Mysql info on it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html

Comment: I feel embarrassed, I was doing INSERT INTO tbl VALUE (SELECT ...). Thank you.